# ZEST script authentication using OWASP ZAP

Tags: owasp, zap

I m trying to understand how to record login using ZEST script. Once recording the steps, how to reuse it? I tried multiple times but I'm not able to get the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Define a context
2. Set the Authentication mechanism to scripts
3. Select your Zest script
4. Set relevant Logged In/Out Indicators
5. Add a valid user and password
6. Test it all :)

The following FAQ is for configuring form based auth, but is still mostly relevant for scipts, esp the trouble shooting section: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQformauth

If you're still having problems then the ZAP User Group is probably a better forum for getting support: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

This article may also be of assistance: [Scripting Authenticated Login within ZAP Vulnerability Scanner](https://www.coveros.com/scripting-authenticated-login-within-zap-vulnerability-scanner/)

Comment: Hey @simon-bennetts, How do I run the Zest script in headless mode?

Comment: Its best to test with the GUI as its easier to diagnose issues. Once its all working the same configuration will work equally well in desktop and headless mode.